# Blurry image border effect with clip-path

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to cover text with blurry image border like in this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFg3m.jpg)? The problem is that the picture is contained in trapezoid shaped element. I was reading about `clip-path` and wanted to do the trick with inset `box-shadow` to get this transparent border effect but it is not working and I have no idea how to workaround this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`clip-path` is not that well supported in most browsers [(see this resource)](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path)

Use a graphic program to create that kind of effect and then stack all your layers together. I used Photoshop, but you can use any other graphic program that can save PNGs with an alpha channel (e.g. GIMP)

### Here a step-by-step instruction:

1. Open your image and unlock background layer by double clicking on the lock in the `Layers` window. Then add a mask
   [image: Add mask]
2. Add a gradient to your mask
   [image: Add gradient to mask]
3. Save your image for Web as PNG-24 or PNG with alpha channel. Make sure `Transparency` is checked
   [image]

**Now to the code part:**

```css
.Header {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 488px;
  height: 200px;
  
  /* just some font stuff */
  font: 2.5em sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.Header > div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.Header-layer1 {
  z-index: 1;
}

.Header-layer1 span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 150px;
  top: 50px;
}

.Header-layer2 {
  background: url( https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9fIM.png ) no-repeat left top;
  z-index: 2;
}

.Header-layer3 {
  z-index: 3;
}

.Header-layer3 span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 175px;
  top: 70px;
  color: #ede8d7;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 10px rgba( 0, 0, 0, .05 );
}
```

```html
<div class="Header">
  <div class="Header-layer1">
    <span>Some</span>
  </div>
  <div class="Header-layer2">
    <!-- we add the background image to this layer with CSS -->
  </div>
  <div class="Header-layer3">
    <span>text here</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Image credit](https://www.flickr.com/photos/epredator/36625033406/)